# why a difference of opinion between gcc and gdb

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, labview

GCC thinks I have

```
sql_LV.c:543:35: error: request for member ‘str’ in something not a structure or union
        &(((**functions).String[i]).str)
```

GDB is thinks differently:

```
(gdb) print &(((**functions).String[0]).str)
$1 = (uChar (*)[1]) 0xf550514c
(gdb) print (((**functions).String[0]).str)
$2 = "N"
```

And here's the code:

```
typedef struct {
    int32 cnt;      /* number of bytes that follow */
    uChar str[1];   /* cnt bytes */
} LStr, *LStrPtr, **LStrHandle;

typedef struct {
    int32 dimSize;
    LStrHandle String[1];
    } LStrArry;
typedef LStrArry **LStrArryHdl;

char IsFunction(LStrArryHdl functions, char* InStr, int32 InStrLen) {
    if (functions == NULL) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< (**functions).dimSize; i++) {
        if (strncmp(InStr,
                            &(((**functions).String[i]).str),
                            (InStrLen < ((**functions).String[i].cnt) ? InStrLen : ((**functions).String[i].cnt))
                            ) == 0) return 1; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So what's the discrepancy?  I've included the typedefs.

Comment: Soo what is that `#if 0` doing there? How were you able to compile the code? Don't you get many "undefined identifiers" errors? `GDB is thinks differently` But to run gdb, you had to compile the code. How did you, when you have a compiler error? Anyway, `gcc` is right - `...String[i]` is a `LStr**`, so you have to twice dereference it to get to the member.

Comment: What is the output of `ptype functions` in GDB?

Comment: The `#if 0` is there to prevent a redefinition of that structure.  I'll remove it from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on you just need to break the types down, so in:

```
&(((**functions).String[i]).str)
```

the type of `String[i]` is `LStrHandle`, which is `**LStr`.  And so you can't apply the `.` operator.

If you dereference `String[i]` then you'll have a `*Lstr`, to which `->` could be applied, as in:

```
&((*((**functions).String[i]))->str)
```

The same error has been made with your uses of `.cnt` in the following lines.

I'm also a little suspicious of your use of `&` in this line.  As `str` is defined as `uChar str[1];` (assuming `typedef unsigned char uChar`), then the type of this line `&((*((**functions).String[i]))->str)` will be `unsigned char **`, when I suspect you really wanted `unsigned char *`.  You might want to drop the leading `&`?